# How to move a SAS Created table to a different filegroup in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sas

We have a process, where a table is generated in SAS and we use that SAS generated table to create a table in SQL Server, however, the table is created on a default filegroup, but I need to change the code to specify a different filegroup where it needs to be created because of space constraints. The code as is written on SAS is as follows (below), DBO.TBL_A is the SAS Created table, and DBO.TBL is the table that is to be created in SQL server. What I have tried doing is added that line of code below to specify the file group I want it added to but SAS gives me an error (see pic), I am not very technical on SAS and I am not sure why this line of code is not working. What am I missing?

```
CREATE TABLE DBO.TBL[![enter image description here][1]][1]
AS
SELECT 
  input(&varFileDate, BEST22.) as FileDate  ,
  TRIM(SSN) as SSN              , 
  ExmDescription                , 
  Status                        ,
  ScaledScore                   ,
  ExamDate          
  FROM DBO.TBL_A
  ORDER BY SSN; 

-- I tried the following

CREATE TABLE DBO.TBL
AS
SELECT 
  input(&varFileDate, BEST22.) as FileDate  ,
  TRIM(SSN) as SSN              , 
  ExmDescription                , 
  Status                        ,
  ScaledScore                   ,
  ExamDate          
  FROM DBO.TBL_A
  ORDER BY SSN
  ON [STAGING_DATA_FG02] WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE)
```

I added ON [STAGING_DATA_FG02] WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE); immediately before the ; but it won't work

[image]

Comment: This is because that is not valid SQL syntax in SAS. Are you trying to create the table in a different schema or location in SQL? If so, this would mean changing the output library in SAS using a `libname` statement.

Comment: that `ON [STAGING_DATA_FG02] WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE)` at the end of your create statement is not valid SAS syntax.  If there are options you want to pass into the remote database you might be able to pass them using dataset options on the target dataset name (`DBO.TBL`).  Otherwise create the table first using pass thru SQL (`execute` statement in PROC SQL) and just use SQL INSERT or PROC APPEND.

Comment: So, I am not SAS Savy, I mainly use TSQL, but this process from my understanding creates DBO.TBL_A solely on SAS, and then uses the script above to create to SQL Server. Problem, it creates it on default filegroup. I need to specify a different filegroup w/ more space. Not where where I can do that on the SAS program

Comment: Depends on what the libref `DBO` is.  If it is a connection to your remote database then your `create table` statement is trying to create a table in that remote database.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the libref DBO is a connection to your remote database. So perhaps something like this

```
libname dbo odbc .... ;
```

If you want to tell it create the new table in a different location in the database you might be able to use the [SCHEMA=](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=acreldb&docsetTarget=n1h1m1ethqxwryn1wu68m46hdp1u.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) dataset option.

```
create table dbo.tbl (schema='STAGING_DATA_FG02') ....
```

Otherwise use explicit pass thru to use native SQL syntax to make the table.  That is probably the best option if the source and target are both in that database since then there is no need to move the data to SAS at all.

```
proc sql;
  connect using dbo ;
  execute by dbo (
     ... your remote database code goes here ...
  );
```